# Webdriver wait for complete page to load

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Is there any way to make webdriverio wait for a complete page to load?
I dont want to use browser.setTimeout({ 'pageLoad': 10000 }), because I dont know how much time it will take to load complete page
I tried below code but it didn't worked,

`browser.waitUntil( () => browser.execute(() => document.readyState === 'complete'), { timeout: 60 * 1000, // 60 seconds timeoutMsg: 'Message on failure' } );`

Where exactly I have to put this readyState code in script?
Currently I am adding this LOC after navigating any new page and before code where loading is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your concerns, regarding timeouts. Assuming you are following the page object pattern (https://webdriver.io/docs/pageobjects/), you can add that as a base method for your Page class. For example:

```
  class WhateverPage {

    open(path): void {
        browser.url(path);
        this.waitForPageLoad(); // add your is loaded conditions here
    }

    waitForPageLoad(): void {
      browser.waitUntil(
        () => browser.execute(
          () => document.readyState === 'complete'),
          {
            timeout: 60 * 1000, // 60 seconds
            timeoutMsg: 'Message on failure'
          }
        )
      )
    }
  }
```

Now in your test when you do as a beggining step Page.open() it should wait for the page to be loaded before it does anything else. You can also use the waitForPageLoad method here by itself when you do page transitions. Let me know if this helps!